# Owl-carousel não carrega com array dinâmico angular

Tags: html, angularjs

Galera estou com um grave problema e já tentei de tudo para resolver e até agora nada!

Tenho um CMS para meu site, no site tem vários plugins, criei um array com as imagens, textos, e chamei no site com o *ngFor, funcionou perfeitamente, mas ele era estático. Dai fiz uma requisição HTTP para o meu CMS e montei os arrays, até ai tudo bem, o array foi montado igual ao outro, porém o JS não funciona, parou de funcionar o banner, o owl-carousel também não funciona, nada... nenhuma função JS funciona...

preciso muito da ajuda por favor!! segue abaixo um exemplo de código..

## VIEW

```js
getItensHome() {
    // /************
    // HEADER GERAL
    // *************/
    let headerConfig = {
      stsValue: "A",
      deleteValue: "N"
    }

    // /************
    // GET DEPOIMENTOS
    // *************/
    return this.HttpService.JSON_GET(`https://innsere-rest.herokuapp.com/api/mysql/data/depoimentos/nomePessoa/asc/*/id,hashID,sts,nomePessoa,depoimento/*`, headerConfig)
      .then(
        (res) => {
          this.arDepoimentos = res.json().data;
          console.log(this.arDepoimentos);

        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
        })
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.10/angular.min.js"></script>
<owl-carousel [options]="{items: 1, dots: false, nav: true, margin: 120, loop: true}" [carouselClasses]="['owl-theme', 'row', 'sliding']">
  <div class="item" owl-carousel-item *ngFor="let depoimento of arDepoimentos">
    <p class="description">
      “{{ depoimento.depoimento }}”
    </p>
    <h2 class="nome-pessoa text-right">
      - {{ depoimento.nomePessoa }}
    </h2>
  </div>
</owl-carousel>
```